# How to return in to parent's scope from inline function?

Tags: flutter, dart

So `pickFromFile` is a Future, which returns after some time.  In `reader.onLoadEnd` I'm trying to return, but how can I return to pickFromFile's scope, instead of returning in the scope of inline function, that is given as an argument to onLoadEnd.listen?

```
Future<ByteData> pickFromFile() async
  {
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.multiple = false;
    uploadInput.accept = 'image/*';

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
      // read file content as dataURL
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      if (files.length == 1) {
        final file = files[0];
        final reader = FileReader();

        reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
          var result = reader.result;
          var base64 = result.toString().split(",")[1];
          var bytes = base64Decode(base64);
          return ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
        });
        reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
      }
    });
    uploadInput.click();
  }
```

I have a `then` listener on pickFromFile which does not get called in case I return like in the example above.

Comment: Why not pass in a callback method to pickFromFile that will be invoked from onLoadEnd?

Comment: that's one way, but I was wondering if there is a direct way, rather than using a callback

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself. Completer is what I was looking for.

```
Future<List<Base>> GetItemList(){
  var completer = new Completer<List<Base>>();

  // At some time you need to complete the future:
  completer.complete(new List<Base>());

  return completer.future;
}
```